# How to prompt user to save access file from localhost in MVC 4 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to prompt user to save the access database file on button click.

Below is my controller and view.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult BlankTemplate(string startyear, string endyear)
        {
         try
            {
             blankTemplateFile = "C:\\BlankTemplate\\PTPKCalc_BlankTemplate.accdb";                                         
             string saveAsFileName = blankTemplateFile;        
             System.IO.File.Copy(saveAsFileName, blankTemplateFile + "\\" + Strings.Mid(saveAsFileName, Strings.InStrRev(saveAsFileName, "\\") + 1));  
             byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\BlankTemplate\\PTPKCalc_BlankTemplate.accdb");
             string fileName = "PTPKCalc_BlankTemplate.accdb";
             Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", fileName);
             return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
            }
            catch { }
                return null;   
        }
```

View:

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 60%">
                                Start Year:<br />
                                @(Html.Kendo().Calendar()
                                            .Name("startcalendar"))
                            </td>
    </table>

   <script>
<script>
    BlankTemplate = function () {
        var start = $("#startcalendar").data("kendoCalendar");
        var end = $("#endcalendar").data("kendoCalendar");

        var startyear = kendo.parseDate(start.value())
        var endyear = kendo.parseDate(end.value(), "G")
        $.ajax({
            url: _rootUrl + "KcalcImport/BlankTemplate",
            data: {
                startyear: kendo.toString(new Date(startyear), "d"),
                endyear: kendo.toString(new Date(endyear), "d"),
                templatetype: "blanktemplate"
            },         
        });
    }
</script>
```

Simply trying to prompt user to save this access database template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldnt try and download a file using AJAX. Instead just do a regular POST from a button in a form. Decorate your action method with HttpPost.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BlankTemplate(string startyear, string endyear)
{
    // put the code you had before here and return a FileResult
}
```

Then just use a regular old form with a submit button to fetch it. Since you need to grab the dates from the calendar, you'll have to do some jQuery to fetch them and slap them into hidden fields.

In your view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("BlankTemplate", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "accessForm" }))
{
    @Html.Hidden("startyear", "", new { id = "startyear" })
    @Html.Hidden("endyear", "", new { id = "endyear" })
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
}
```

And the jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#accessForm").submit(function () {
            var start = $("#startcalendar").data("kendoCalendar");
            var end = $("#endcalendar").data("kendoCalendar");

            $("#startyear").val(kendo.parseDate(start.value()));
            $("#endyear").val(kendo.parseDate(end.value(), "G"));
        });
    });
</script>
```